# QLineEdit deny non-English character input

Tags: input, qt5, qlineedit

I have a problem with QLineEdit in Qt 5. When I try input some non-English character it still write English ones regardless of what is the keyboard layout.

If I input text in some text editor and than copy&paste, text input correctly.

In qt 4 everything works perfect.

Code from ui file.

```
<widget class="QLineEdit" name="leSearch">
<property name="maxLength">
<number>200</number>
</property>
<property name="placeholderText">
<string>Search here</string>
</property>
</widget>
```

Ubuntu 13.10 x32
Qt Creator 2.8.1
Based on Qt 5.1.1 (GCC 4.6.1, 32 bit)
Built on Aug 26 2013 at 13:34:46
From revision c3ed746c24

Please help!
Thanks

Comment: Which platform is that, and which keyboard layout?

Comment: What do you mean by platform? Russian keyboard layout.

Comment: Do you use Unity as desktop? I tried with a simple example (QApplication + QLineEdit with above properties) and it works fine with Russian layout. Opensuse 64bit, KDE, official Qt 5.1.1 download.

Comment: Yes, Unity. Thanks for information. I'm going to try it with Gnome.

Comment: I've tested all those thing and found the problem in ibus system of Ubuntu 13.10. But I don't know how to solve it. Under Windows and Debian everything works.